# Poor SCP performance under windows

Tags: scp, winscp, msys, msys2

I'm seeing some performance issues with SCP under windows, in short, I'm maxing out at 61 MB/sec on a 1Gbps Ethernet connection.

Now, Windows itself have detected the connection as 1Gbps, and I've ran some tests to the same servers over SMB, which gave me 115+ MB/sec. So, both the network interface and the physical network between the devices seems to be fine.

Also, I'm dual booting on this workstation, and my primary OS, which is Linux based, has no issues with SCP between the two machines, and it gives me full throttle. Which tells me, its not a CPU bottleneck (which would also be quite unlikely in the first place, as the machine is sporting a 9900K).

So, in summery, there must be something up with my SCP installation on windows. I'm not a native Windows speaker, so im not entirely sure how to proceed, as of now, I tried the following SCP binaries:

- msys2 provided scp in a msys2 console
- winscp

and they both give me the same poor results. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I felt like I wanted to share my solution in case somebody else encounters the same issue.

I resolved this by using Windows subsystem for Linux, I installed Arch Linux on WSL, and using the SCP binary through the WSL provided bash, resolved the issue and gave me the same throughput as I get under native Linux.